# TypeScript not allowing comparison between .data() and numbers/string

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript1.6

Due to the strongly typed nature of typescript it seems to have issues when comparing the result of a jQuery .data() call and a simple type like a number of string.

For example:

```
var dataValue = $("#myDiv").data("div-index");

if(dataValue === 0)
{
    alert("first item");
}
```

The above will yield an error of `Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'JQuery' and 'number'.`

TypeScript sees the result of `.data()` as type JQuery and so evaluations between that, as expected with a complex type, is not possible.

The only workaround so far is to call `.toString()` on the end of the `.data()` call, however this means modifying all current `.data()` calls and their comparisons. This also makes numeric comparison such as `>` impossible as we cannot compare between a string and number.

This issue only seems to be occurring after updating to TypeScript 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of `jquery.d.ts`. I noticed this too. There was a bug that would make it use `data(obj: { [key: string]: any; }): JQuery;` instead of `.data(key: string): any`. It was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/commit/1d6c126e8ead25892ded5a32df2e813ffad06905#diff-ef3bb11c6dc0a0d1083ee170370ff1df).

Once you upgrade and `data(key: string)`'s return type is `any`, you can tell the compiler you know it's going to be a number by using a type assertion:

```
var dataValue = $("#myDiv").data("div-index") as number;

if (dataValue === 0)
{
    alert("first item");
}
```

Comment: As someone not familiar with git, how will I know what version (if any) this change is in? The same package is listed as having the latest stable version of 2.2.9 in NuGet.

Comment: @Frayt it's fixed in that NuGet package. I just checked.

Answer (score 3):

It is look like a bug. I have just reviewed [jQuery.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L1547) file and found your return type, but for another method overloading.

### Solution

Just try to add `<any>` above your method call:

```
var dataValue = <any>$("#myDiv").data("div-index");

if(dataValue === 0)
{
    alert("first item");
}
```

and this case would be work for you

### Additional Case

Also you can report this issue on official [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new) issue thread and [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/new) issue thread

Answer (score 1):

Actually, according to [jQuery.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L1553) the call to `$("#myDiv").data("div-index")` is returning type `<any>`.

Could it be, that the value you've stored in the element is actually a jQuery object?